# Code sample being parsed incorrectly?

Tags: support

Searched for related posts, but none seemed to match this.  Hence this post.

Take look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613205/spring-2-5-login-not-responding-even-with-the-correct-username-password). It contains an XML code snippet which is specified as a `code sample`.  If you look carefully, the section after `/*` is faded in color, indicating that the rest of the contents are `comments`.  However there is no matching `*/` to indicate end of comment.

Is this a bug? If not, how to ensure that the example above is not shown in faded text?

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged Java, so the code prettifier is told to format all code blocks as Java. Since `/*` starts a multi-line comment in Java, it's grey.

I'm not sure if it makes sense to tag this sort of question as XML. It would fix the formatting, but the question isn't really an XML problem. However, I just tested this out by temporarily changing the tags and it did indeed work.

Comment: You can also add an HTML comment before the block if you don't want to change the tags; see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting